# How to work with strings in a loop - MatLab

Tags: string, matlab, loops

I have a big cell array (m) that contains a column with strings and values.

Does anyone know how to work with strings in a loop?
For example:
If they were numbers, I would do

```
  for i = 1:100
       plot m(:,i)
  end
```

Is there any form to work like these using strings?
I got 74 different strings (that's why I want to use a loop)!

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: And change the title please, it's like getting an answer: "*Answering your question*" and then the real answer.

Comment: i think it would be good , if we downvote a question and then we must write comments why we downvote ? i see 3 downvote and ZERO comments i feel bad.

Comment: @simplecoder look again, there are 5 comments (including this and another one below :D)

Comment: That would be Matlab code.

Comment: i'm very sorry for this inconvinience, i'm new on stackoverflow (and also in matlab).

Comment: @Luiz Instead of `plot ...` write `str = m(i, :)` and in each iteration variable `str` will a different string from the matrix `m`. Also, I know that asking on StackOverflow is easy, but you'll benefit a lot more from reading a good MATLAB tutorial and trying things for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with elements in a cell array, use curly braces {} to retrieve the data stored at each cell index, as in the following loop:

```
for i = 1:74
    str = m{i};
    % do something with string
end
```